# ¿Como solucionar este error en macchanger en mac?

Tags: linux, redes, router, macos

Resulta que acabo de instalar macchanger o eso creo, pero no puedo hacer nada ya que me arroja este error:

> ```
> ERROR:   Use macchanger as root: sudo macchanger [option] [device]
> ```

Y si ejecuto el comando `sudo macchanger --option` me devuelve:

> ```
> Usage: sudo macchanger [option] [device]
> ```

Luego me da una lista con `Options`...

¿Alguien sabe de qué se trata y como solucionarlo?

Comment: Este sitio es para preguntas relacionadas con programación, así que dudo que te contesten y más cuando apenas aportas datos de tu escenario. Aún así, el error que te sale se debe a que macchanger necesita permisos de root y tal como arroja el error, debes usar sudo si no estás en la cuenta de root.

Comment: Primero haz: **sudo ifconfig** para ver las posibilidades de [device], luego con el *device* ya encontrado, es: **sudo macchanger -r enp2s0** siendo enp2s0 tu tarjeta de red a la que quieres cambiar la mac y -r por una random.